# Update Oracle Database from CSV sheet which is locate on different server

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

My requirement is When any sheet such that CSV, PDF and may be different type sheet which is locate on different server. I want when these sheet got update then My oracle database which is on different server will be updated.

Comment: And how is the database supposed to know that these files on a different server have been touched?

Comment: From my point of view, you'd have to check *previous* hash value for each file and compare it to *current* one. If it differs, perform update. How to do that? Using a job - either operating system one, or database job. If latter, you'd have to have access to directory that contains those files.  BTW, what is that "update", really? Set some flag that file has changed, or load file into some BLOB column, or ...?

Comment: How can i load file from other servers?

Comment: By using the UTL_FILE package.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot for reply...Could you please share any document.